# Does TestCafe fit into BDD and cucumber?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber, bdd, testcafe

I understand TestCafe attempts to replace Webdriver based test frameworks like Selenium. I couldn't find examples of integration with BDD (cucumber) yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find a demonstration of integration TestCafe into CucumberJS tests in the [testcafe-cucumber-demo](https://github.com/helen-dikareva/testcafe-cucumber-demo) GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If you need both BDD and a standard way of working with TestCafe, this repo might be helpfull: [testcafe-starter](https://github.com/hdorgeval/testcafe-starter)